# Python Matplotlib pyplot histogram

Tags: python

I am plotting a histogram of a fairly simple simulation. On the histogram the last two columns are merged and it looks odd. Please finde attached below the code and the plot result.

Thanks in advance!

```
   import numpy as np
   import random
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   N = 100000
   results = []
   # first round
   for i in range(N):
       X1 = random.choice(die)
       if X1 > 4:
           results.append(X1)
       else:
           X2 = random.choice(die)
           if X2 > 3:
               results.append(X2)
           else:
               X3 = random.choice(die)
               results.append(X3)

   plt.hist(results)
   plt.ylabel('Count')
   plt.xlabel('Result');
   plt.title("Mean results: " + str(np.mean(results)))
   plt.show()
```

The output looks like this. I dont understand why the last two columns are stuck together.

[image: Histogram]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, matplotlib divides the range of the input into 10 equally sized bins. All bins span a half-open interval `[x1,x2)`, but the rightmost bin includes the end of the range. Your range is `[1,6]`, so your bins are `[1,1.5)`, `[1.5,2)`, ..., `[5.5,6]`, so all the integers end up in the first, third, etc. odd-numbered bins, but the sixes end up in the tenth (even) bin.

To fix the layout, specify the bins:

```
# This will give you a slightly different layout with only 6 bars
plt.hist(results, bins=die + [7])
# This will simulate your original plot more closely, with empty bins in between
plt.hist(results, bins=np.arange(2, 14)/2)
```

The last bit generates the number sequence `2,3,...,13` and then divides each number by 2, which gives `1, 1.5, ..., 6.5` so that the last bin spans `[6,6.5]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second line of code you provided got me the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell matplotlib that you want the histogram to match the bins.
Otherwise matplotlib choses the default value of 10 for you - in this case, that doesn't round well.

```
# ... your code ...

plt.hist(results, bins=die)  # or bins = 6
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Result');
plt.title("Mean results: " + str(np.mean(results)))
plt.show()
```

Full documentation is here: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't, but you can try it.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(results , kde = False)
```